# invalid lvalue - boolean in if

Tags: c

I'm trying to hack a prime-test for my c program. Unfortunately I'm running into problems and into circles really.

using this expression:

this is my full code

```
int prim(int x)
{
 int i,j;
 for(i=x;i>0;i--)
 {
  if(x%i==0 && i=!x)
  {
   printf("%i no prime %i",x);
  }
 }
}
```

gives me this error: 10 D:\C\L2\main.c invalid lvalue in assignment

I dont understand why this is happening. any helpers?

Comment: It would really help a lot if you told us what this was supposed to do. What do you think `i=!x` does?

Comment: added the code. hope it is more clear now

Comment: oh and thanks for the downvote. I really enjoy mature people on stackoverflow.

Comment: People just don't consider "fix my trivial syntax errors given a compiler error that says the exact line and precisely describes the error" questions particularly interesting.

Comment: triviality is just a point of view. for me this is insanely difficult not coming from a programming background. and yes i've googled it. it just frustrating someone downvoting for no apparent reason but thats the community I guess. Beginners are not welcome.

Comment: @blacksmth Beginners are welcome actually. Everyone needs to start at some point. And some are 'more gifted' than others. Everyone here (should) know(s) this. And personally I understand quite fine how it is to be confronted with an error message, which makes no sense to me. So don't feel bad about a downvote or two. As you may have noticed, even if your question may get downvoted, people are willing to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, you're mixing up the operators somewhat badly.

Try this:

```
if((x%i) == 0 && i != x)
```

The brackets will make sure, that the modulo is executed first before comparing it with `==` (`==` => Compare, `=` => Assign)

A little explanation:

First off, you used assignment operators (the single =). That means, you told the computer to take the value of '0' and assign it to x%i. However, x%i isn't a variable, but rather an equation. That's what your compiler complained about. 'Invalid lvalue' -> 'Can't assign to value on the left hand of the equation mark'. At the other error, you mixed up the order of things. The '!' mark means 'NOT'. So it's i NOT EQUAL x. What you wrote was: i EQUAL NOT x. That COULD actually have worked, but most likely not give you the desired result. (Since NOT variable inverts it).

`invert` in this context means, that it takes every one and every zero in the number and switches them around. Assuming you have 1000 0001 (unsigned char), it'd be 0111 1110 after the inversion.

Comment: This one did the trick. Would you mind explaining what exactly went bad with my version :( I'd love to learn about my mistakes here

Comment: Sure thing. First off, you used `assignment operators` (the single `=`). That means, you told the computer to take the value of '0' and assign it to `x%i`. However, `x%i` isn't a variable, but rather an equation. That's what your compiler complained about. 'Invalid lvalue' -> 'Can't assign to value on the left hand of the equation mark'. At the other error, you mixed up the order of things. The '!' mark means 'NOT'. So it's `i NOT EQUAL x`. What you wrote was: `i EQUAL NOT x`. That COULD actually have worked, but most likely not give you the desired result. (Since NOT variable inverts it).

Comment: +1 since you're the only one who actually explained (in a comment, but better than nothing) the problem instead of just giving an answer. I think you should add the explanation to the answer.

Comment: @effeffe Thank you kindly. In my experience, most people don't want lengthy explanations, but rather quick answers, straight and to the point. Of course, if someone cares to ask, I'll explain to any detail :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on your full code the issues are:

1) error: you have your `!=` backwards. this is not the same as `=!`

```
if(x%i==0 && i!=x)  // this is correct
```

2) warning: you're telling printf you want to print two variables but you're only giving it one:

```
printf("%i no prime",x);  // this is correct
```

3) warning: you've got your function marked as returning an int, but it returns nothing:

```
void prim(int x)  // this is correct
```

Comment: what kind of debugger do you use?

Comment: @blacksmth - You mean compiler? my head. ;) those aren't real warning messages just issues I see... but when I *do* compile code I use `gcc -Wall -Werror`. If you really meant debugger, I use `gdb`

Answer (score 2):

```
if(x%i=0 && i=!x)
```

You want:

```
if (((x % i) == 0) && (i != x))
```

Some other things:

You test if one is a divisor, which it always is.

Why start with `x` only to have to test for it? Why not start the loop at `x-1` and get rid of one half of the test in the `if`?

You say `prim` returns an `int`, but it doesn't.

Comment: Fixed. Missing open parenthesis.

Comment: I would also check the dividers starting from **sqrt(x)** to 2. (or vice versa)

Answer (score 1):

The usual one. You have assignment in the condition, not equality check.

Try this instead:

```
if(x%i == 0 && i!=x)
```

Also, even though they are superfluous, I would use more parentheses (it helps me a lot)

```
if( (x%i == 0) && (i!=x) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your code carefully.  You have `x%1 = 0` when it should be `==`.

Answer (score 1):

`if(x%i==0 && i!=x)` use this

`=` is an assignment operator and `==` is an comparison operator

and replace `=!` with `!=`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of problems here.

1. In C `==` is used for equality checks but you are using `=` which is assignment.
2. Inequality (not equals) is `!=` not `=!`

Hence the code should be

```
if (x % i == 0 && i != x) { 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int prim(int x)
{
 int i,j;
 for(i=x;i>0;i--)
 {
  if(x%i==0 && i=!x)
  {
   printf("%i no prime %i",x);  // Error 1
  }
 }
}
```

(Error 1 :  you are trying to print two integer values with one variable x..

give another x for %i or remove %i from printf statement.)

Comment: You have only repeated one of the earlier given answers.